# Xcode problem with Source Control lost project

Tags: xcode, version-control

I lost my project from sorce control only pods. How to add project again?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After merging, if there have any conflict *.xcworkspace file can't be opened. So you can manually merge opening *.xcworkspace file with notes and other programs. Or you can go to your previous commit.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```